# Create tasks from lists - Airflow

Tags: python, list, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a requirement where I have a list of lists like

```
[[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l]]
```

Now I want to create tasks in DAG like below

```
a >> b >> c >> d

e >> f >> g >> h

i >> j >> k >> l
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Share your attempt

Comment: Does a,b,.. represent Operators?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the handy `chain()` function to do this in 1 line.

```py
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain

[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l] = [DummyOperator(task_id=f"{i}") for i in "abcdefghijkl"]
chain([a,e,i], [b,f,j], [c,g,k], [d,h,l])
```

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty neat. Nice answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a,b,c,... are operators - the below should do the job (mocking airflow operator)

```
class Operator:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_downstream(self, other):
        print(f'{self}: setting {other} as downstream')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


a = Operator('a')
b = Operator('b')
c = Operator('c')
d = Operator('d')
e = Operator('e')
f = Operator('f')
lst = [[a, b, c], [e, f, d]]

for oper_lst in lst:
    for i in range(0, len(oper_lst) - 1):
        oper_lst[i].set_downstream(oper_lst[i + 1])
```

output

```
a: setting b as downstream
b: setting c as downstream
e: setting f as downstream
f: setting d as downstream
```

Answer (score 0):

```
op_lists = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l]]
for op_list in op_lists:
    for i in range(len(op_list) - 1):
        op_list[i] >> op_list[i + 1]
```

EDIT: I didn't see balderman's answer. He was first

Answer (score 0):

With a,...,l being nodes and >> describing the arcs, we can write the nested list as a dictionary and then use this object for a directed acyclic graph. Depending on your data (e.g) the nested lists and the connections between them you can adapt the code. In the example above, we have three lists converting to three arcs. One could the list object to a dictionary like this:

```
graph = [["a","b","c","d"],["e","f","g","h"],["i","j","k","l"]]

dic_list = []
z = {}
for i in range(len(graph)):
    b = dict(zip(graph[i][::1], list(graph[i][1::1])))
    dic_list.append(b)
    z = {**z, **dic_list[i]}
```

and then use this standard code from the python documentation to build a DAG out of it like this:

```
   def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if not graph.has_key(start):
            return []
        paths = []
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
        return paths
```

Does this answer your question?